# i want to create CustomCell But it give some error, How to Solve it?? error is describe below

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
}
cell.cellDate.text=@"date";
cell.cellDescription.text =@"Description";
cell.cellImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
cell.cellTitle.text = @"Title";
NSLog([cell Description]);
return cell;
```

}

```
 NSLog([cell Description]);
```

Return null

Above is my Method It gives below Error:
here

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource
>   must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: allocate your custom cell in inside if (cell == nil) {}

Comment: What @vitality is showing you is correct. Bottom line is you need to initialize a new cell. So after the `(cell==nil)`, just insert this line: `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating a new cell inside your if `(cell == nil)` bit. You need to allocate a new `UITableViewCell` to return.

The way de-queueing works is:

1. ask table view for a re-useable cell with a `CellIdentifier`
2. If the cell is nil then allocate a new cell using your `CellIdentifier` so that it can be re-used in the future.

So you could go something like:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
//Ask for a cell with the cell identifier
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//If the cell is nil
if (cell == nil) 
{
//Allocate a new cell with the identifier
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];//put your actual init method here
}
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
cell.cellDate.text=@"date";
cell.cellDescription.text =@"Description";
cell.cellImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
cell.cellTitle.text = @"Title";
NSLog([cell Description]);
return cell;
```

hope this helps

Comment: geting This error after implimenting new code: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CustomCell", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MasterViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: perfoming this can't load CustomCell.xib into tableview cell do you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
}
```

To :

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
}
```

Comment: You did show the exact same thing, only you added an extra check for a `cell==nil`, which is always going to be nill

Comment: CustomCell *cell = nil; make every time create a new cell in table view,it not reuse cell..

Comment: This will always return nil - you at some point need to allocate the cell with the re-use identifier. The tableview collects these and re-uses them if possible, but if it needs a new cell then you need to allocate it.

Comment: And how will it be initialized? A new cell is never being created.

Comment: You don't need to change the `CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` line. This is correct. What you need to do is create a new cell, if the cell is nil, i.e. a cell is not available for reuse...

Comment: @Rushi: changed But Can't work give error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from

Comment: @JigPatel Update the code with the correct code, as Rushi's previous code was wrong and it will work

Comment: Rushi Lefteris :> still gives error error is : Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CustomCell", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MasterViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: guys i change above comment this is because not adding file into compaling source

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here// Customize the appearance of table view cell
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:  CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
     cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

cell.cellDate.text=@"date";
cell.cellDescription.text =@"Description";
cell.cellImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
cell.cellTitle.text = @"Title";
return cell;


}
```

don't forget to add .m file of customcell in compile source tab